# (Python Type Hint): Is it possible to hint variable-type to class will be declared later?

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

Take a look at following python snippet.

```python
class classA:
    var_a : classB
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class classB:
    var_b : int
    def __init__(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

This'll cause `NameError: name 'classB' is not defined`. Of course, if we define `classB` before `classA`, there won't be any problems.

But I'm just checking whether it's possible to do so without switching `classA` `classB` definition positions. (For documentation/readability purposes for others)

- Is it possible to hint variable type to class will be declared later?
- Or, Am I asking wrong questions?

Comment: In this case, just change the order. But in general: you can use strings, so `var_a: 'ClassB'`